# dynamic keys in Typescript combined with static keys

Tags: typescript

I am trying to have a Typescript interface which allows dynamic keys in combination with further data, that is not dynamic. But it seems as though whenever I declare dynamic keys - is this possible at all?

```
export interface Templates {
    [key: string]: Template;
    reportSource: string;
}
```

above code results in:

```
Property 'reportSource' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type 'Template'.ts(2411)
```

This compiles, but is quite suboptimal, because now every key can be either of type Template or string, while I am trying to achieve that only reportSource can be of type string and all other keys are of type Template.

```
export interface Templates {
    [key: string]: Template | string;
    reportSource: string;
}
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types ctrl+f for "If you want to add members" and check the following examples